# Adding Semantic UI React value of Form.Select into variable I post into my Django API

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm new to React and I try to understand how I can add Form.Select value into my variables that I post into my Django API.

When I only use Form.Input it works ok but when I add a Form.Select value doesn't passed into the userform.

I saw that using `event.target.elements.inputname.value` is not possible for `Form.Select`, but after a lot of hours trying to make this works ... it looks like I'm unable to do it.

errors shown is : *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined*

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot !!!

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react'

import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'

//import axios from 'axios'

const options = [
    { key: 'm', text: 'Male', value: 'male' },
    { key: 'f', text: 'Female', value: 'female' },
  ]

class MyClass extends React.Component{


    handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const aa = event.target.elements.aa.value
        const bb = event.target.elements.bb.value
        const cc = event.target.elements.cc.value

        //axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blabla', {
        //    aa: aa,
        //    bb: bb,
        //    cc: cc,
        //})
        //    .then(res => console.log(res))
        //    .catch(err => console.log(err))

        console.log(aa, bb, cc)

    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                    <Form.Input name="aa" placeholder='...' />
                    <Form.Input name="bb" placeholder='...' />
                    <Form.Select
                        name="cc"
                        options={options}
                        placeholder='...'
                    />
                    <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
                </Form>
            </div>         
        )
    }

}

export default MyClass
```

Comment: Use `onChange` handler on each of the inputs to update state as in this demo https://codesandbox.io/s/9y4uv?module=/example.js. Note I created that demo in 10 seconds from the semetic react docs by clicking on "CodeSandbox" in the `<Form>` example

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It helped me !